# shinydashboardPlus flipBox - can see back content through front side

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, shinydashboard

[example photo link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6p9h.png)

I am using flipBox from shinydashboardPlus, for my first flipBox everything works well, then since the second one I can see back content through front side.
I don't understand why because the code for the first flipBox and the others are the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found the problem it was inside DT package. I used DT with pagelength parameter which connected to a reactive function in shiny, usually it doesn't raise a problem but here I guess there is a conflict between DT and shinydashboardPlus. After I commented pagelength everything works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my own problem.
I displayed DT datatable inside flipbox which is the back content.
Inside DT, I used a **pagelength parameter** which correspond to the length of dataframe so it is connected with a **shiny reactive**.

Usually this works, for example if I only remove flipbox everything will display correctly without error.

But here I think it may have a conflict between flipbox and DT with reactive as parameter for pagelength. In the end I just commented pagelength, then my flipbox works well.